# Form loading error in NetBeans Matisse

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, netbeans-7, matisse

I am new to JAVA desktop application development and initially started to create all classes under the default package. Later I learned that this is not good practice, so I moved my classes to different packages according to their functionality. As a part of this shifting, I moved my GUI class along with two custom JPanel components into a package (bd.ac.du.bmpt.gui) by refactoring. I then did a clean and build on my project, and ran the application. Everything seems to work fine. No compilation or runtime error or anything. But when I tried switching to design view in my GUI class, it shows form loading error which are all related to two custom JPanel component.

[image: Form loading error in NetBeansMatisse]

And it throws these exceptions:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GPanel
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.FormClassLoader.findClass(FormClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.ClassPathUtils.loadClass(ClassPathUtils.java:114)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormUtils.loadClass(FormUtils.java:1474)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.PersistenceObjectRegistry.loadClass(PersistenceObjectRegistry.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:718)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:530)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:312)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor$2.run(FormEditor.java:348)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:293)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1363)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:322)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormData(FormEditor.java:345)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormEditorSupport.loadOpeningForm(FormEditorSupport.java:462)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.loadForm(FormDesignerTC.java:279)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.access$300(FormDesignerTC.java:87)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC$PreLoadTask$1.run(FormDesignerTC.java:268)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GPanel
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.FormClassLoader.findClass(FormClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.ClassPathUtils.loadClass(ClassPathUtils.java:114)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormUtils.loadClass(FormUtils.java:1474)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.PersistenceObjectRegistry.loadClass(PersistenceObjectRegistry.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:718)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:530)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:312)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor$2.run(FormEditor.java:348)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:293)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1363)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:322)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormData(FormEditor.java:345)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormEditorSupport.loadOpeningForm(FormEditorSupport.java:462)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.loadForm(FormDesignerTC.java:279)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.access$300(FormDesignerTC.java:87)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC$PreLoadTask$1.run(FormDesignerTC.java:268)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GridPanel
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.FormClassLoader.findClass(FormClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.ClassPathUtils.loadClass(ClassPathUtils.java:114)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormUtils.loadClass(FormUtils.java:1474)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.PersistenceObjectRegistry.loadClass(PersistenceObjectRegistry.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:718)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:530)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:312)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor$2.run(FormEditor.java:348)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:293)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1363)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:322)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormData(FormEditor.java:345)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormEditorSupport.loadOpeningForm(FormEditorSupport.java:462)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.loadForm(FormDesignerTC.java:279)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.access$300(FormDesignerTC.java:87)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC$PreLoadTask$1.run(FormDesignerTC.java:268)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GPanel
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.FormClassLoader.findClass(FormClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.ClassPathUtils.loadClass(ClassPathUtils.java:114)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormUtils.loadClass(FormUtils.java:1474)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.PersistenceObjectRegistry.loadClass(PersistenceObjectRegistry.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:718)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:530)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:312)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor$2.run(FormEditor.java:348)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:293)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1363)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:322)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormData(FormEditor.java:345)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormEditorSupport.loadOpeningForm(FormEditorSupport.java:462)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.loadForm(FormDesignerTC.java:279)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.access$300(FormDesignerTC.java:87)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC$PreLoadTask$1.run(FormDesignerTC.java:268)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: GPanel
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.ProjectClassLoader.findClass(ProjectClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.FormClassLoader.findClass(FormClassLoader.java:83)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.project.ClassPathUtils.loadClass(ClassPathUtils.java:114)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormUtils.loadClass(FormUtils.java:1474)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.PersistenceObjectRegistry.loadClass(PersistenceObjectRegistry.java:98)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:718)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.restoreComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:850)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadComponent(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:994)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:530)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.GandalfPersistenceManager.loadForm(GandalfPersistenceManager.java:312)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor$2.run(FormEditor.java:348)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:293)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1363)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:322)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormEditor.loadFormData(FormEditor.java:345)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormEditorSupport.loadOpeningForm(FormEditorSupport.java:462)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.loadForm(FormDesignerTC.java:279)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC.access$300(FormDesignerTC.java:87)
    at org.netbeans.modules.nbform.FormDesignerTC$PreLoadTask$1.run(FormDesignerTC.java:268)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:697)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: whats GPanel, there everything started and ended

Comment: GPanel is one of the custom Jpanels I have used. I added it to Pallete manager and used in GUI by drag n drop.

Comment: Try restoring the `.form` from backup.

Comment: well, I already tried this. Sadly, it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

OK. Thanks Guys. I found the problem and solved it.

The problem was in extra generated code by Matisse. Refactoring didn't change the class names for those two custom JPanel components. I had to modify them manually both in java source and .form data. For example:  GPanel -> bd.ac.du.bmpt.GPanel

Comment: doooh ... that's even worse than the my worst prejudices against builders ;-) +1 for finding it